Unable to call Learning API in SAP CPI
I want to call the following field names with value in CPI job, but the learning URL is not working with http adapter: https://xxxx-stage.plateau.com/learning/odatav4/public/user/PsaUserLearningHistory showing 400 error, fields to find are in this entity. I know this is the entity when I downloaded report with XML document, so this is the entity and the oauth2 cred are working fine too, when I used OData adapter with learningHistory entity it also got some fields but when deployed gave 500 internal error. Any solution to this problem?
In CPI, I have to call LMS API URL to get the following fields:

User Id
Entity Title
Legal Entity Id
Grade
Completion Date
Total Hours
Credit hours
Comments
Completion Status Id
Completion Status


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://xxxx-stage.plateau.com/learning/odatav4/public/user/UserLearningHistory/v1/$metadata is the address i am passing, but couldnt find the entities of it
